# changing the validity of lots when making an MIGO

Tags: abap, sap-erp

does anyone know which "Profile / Role" user allows changing the validity of lots/products when using MIGO tcode?

How can I denied specific users from doing it without the user-exit?

best regards

Comment: By "validity" you means PO validity start and end dates?

Comment: Ei thank you for the reply :) I have create a specific role and whoever have that role i use userexit that display (e) message. Thanks man,  cheers

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I have created a specific role and whoever has that role I use user-exit exit_sapmm07m_001 that display (e) message. Thanks, everyone